# Validating a drawing

Tags: javascript, character

If I wanted to draw the character "二" with my fingers, Google keyboard can accurately recognize this on their Chinese keyboard version as 二. I've seen this work in multiple of websites and apps which I have always wondered how they would detect it so well.

One theory comes to mind, to retrieve the pixels from beginning and end point of the drawn input, and then compare in pixels to see how much the original character and the user's drawing overlap each other? If the overlap rate matches over 70% in pixels, then it will output the correct desired character.

Comment: To draw a character on the screen, you use a font. I don't see what this has to do with comparing pixels or keyboards.

Comment: @bergi we can also draw it like a pencil simulation.

Comment: @Bergi: I believe he is referring to drawing-based character input, like [here](http://jisho.org/#handwriting).

Comment: @amadan Brilliant!! Exactly what I mean! Thank you for the extra clarification!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pixel overlap would be a very inaccurate method. Imagine if you draw your first line a bit too low, but your second perfectly; 三 would be recognised with 67% over 二 with 50% coverage. Imagine if both of your lines were just a bit off; you'd get a space instead.

One way to do it is to recognise and classify [individual strokes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroke_(CJKV_character)#Roman_letter_naming_convention) based on the direction and bends in the stroke (not from the image, but from mouse data collected as the user paints the stroke), then look up the sequence of strokes in a character database. You'd need a database with character strokes. I am almost certain that [jisho.org](http://jisho.org/#handwriting) that I linked in comments, and many other similar sites, employ this method.

Another good way would be to use a [neural networks](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/reports/2016/pdfs/262_Report.pdf) to recognise the bitmap of the input image; this requires many training examples for all characters. Unlike the previous method, this method can recognise even cursive-style input (i.e. with strokes flowing into each other) - as long as the training was exhaustive enough.

There's many more specific techniques one can find by looking for "Handwritten Kanji Recognition" or "Handwritten Chinese Character Recognition" (and Japanese/Chinese equivalents, like 手書き漢字認識 or 手写汉字识别) through [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com).

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I was looking for! :)